# unable to update Magento to latest version from 2.2.4 to 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.2.4, setup, magento-upgrade

I am trying to update Magento 2.2.4 to Magento 2.3 via composer but I am getting below error:

> **Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

```
 Problem 1:
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.0.3 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage ^1.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.0.3].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.0.3 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer ^1.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.0.3].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I did run below commands:

```
1: composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.0 --no-update
2: composer require –dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 –no-update
3: composer update
```

Comment: have check from here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#upgrade-cli-upgr

Comment: after composer update remove cache and generated folders

Comment: then do setup:upgrade

Comment: then run setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: composer update command gives above error

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.3.0/dev/tools/UpgradeScripts/pre_composer_update_2.3.php
php -f pre_composer_update_2.3.php -- --root='<path/to/magento/install/dir>' --repo=https://repo.magento.com/
composer update
rm -rf <path/to/magento/install/dir>/var/cache/*
rm -rf <path/to/magento/install/dir>/var/page_cache/*
rm -rf <path/to/magento/install/dir>/generated/code/*
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#upgrade-cli-script